# Export runnable jars from Eclipse without libraries

Tags: eclipse, executable-jar

I am trying to export an individual runnable class from a larger project. This specific class does not depend on the project libraries.

In `Export->Java->Runnable JAR file -> Library handling` there are options to extract, package or copy the required libraries, but not to simply omit them.

I really don't need them, moreover the library export fails in my situation.

How can I export it without libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [far jar plugin](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/) supports this.

When you export a java project containing jars using the `File -> Export -> Other -> One Jar Exporter`, in the `Select files for Fat Jar` page of the wizard you can choose not to include the libraries like so :

[image]

The jar thus exported works fine.

Comment: Many thanks Ashutosh, upvote +1. Using FatJar works but I had to deselect all jars individually, more than 60 jars in my case. I don't want to do this everytime I export one of my main classes (and I have different ones so I cannot simply save settings), so I am waiting for another answer with a more simple solution.

Comment: Thanks. If you click on the `Save Settings` button, it might save your jar selection. Also, you might want to click on the `Export ANT` to get a build file which will build the fat jar automatically for you and shall preserver you jar selection settings.

Comment: `Export ANT` solved it, thanks. In there I was able to remove all library copy commands. Answer accepted.