# Fat Jar Plug-in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, fat

I need to extract a fat jar.
The common jar does not answer me because it only works through the command prompt typing java -jar meujar.jar with double click does not transition the screens, I need to execute with double click, so also when converting to .exe it does not transition the screens
I installed the Fat Jar Plug-in in eclipse: https://sourceforge.net/projects/fjep/).

Eclipse version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)

Extract the jar to the eclipse plugins folder and run eclipse using the eclipse-clean command, as directed: http://fjep.sourceforge.net/

However, to export I must access File -> Export -> Other -> One Jar Exporter ([Export runnable jars from Eclipse without libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953381/export-runnable-jars-from-eclipse-without-libraries)), but in Eclipse there is no Other option and none of the available options has the Fat Jar, as shown in the image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA5LZ.png)

Comment: Eclipse Luna is more than 8 years and 14 releases behind. Get the current Eclipse and export it as _Runnable JAR_ (no additional plugin is required for that).

Comment: Ok, I will try, because in this version Runnable JAR does not transition the screens of my software, I believe q due to dependencies.

Comment: I installed Eclipse Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0)
However, when exporting _Runnable Jar_ does not load any classes in Launch Configuration, so it does not allow chasing, _Next_ and _Finish_ buttons remain disabled.What should I do to load the classes and I select my class to start?

Comment: Please improve your question with an example that can be reproduced with the current Eclipse. Be aware, it is not possible to create a fat JAR when there are dependencies on the modulepath (since a JAR can contain only one module, not multiple modules).

Comment: I got it, it worked. Thanks.